# CMake: How to specify directory where ctest should look for executables?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, ctest

I wanted to integrate ctest to a c++/c project. I use google tests to write unit tests.

Relevant part of my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
...
####### CREATING EXE #######
add_executable(test_exe main.cpp test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_exe GTest::GTest GTest::Main)
set_target_properties (test_exe PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR})
add_test(test_exe test_exe)
```

As you can see i specified the output directory of my executable (UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR).

The executable works fine on its own when I use the terminal:

```
cd <UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR>
./test_exe
```

I want to use ctest to execute my tests. So I go to the "ctest folder" generated by cmake. Here I want to use ctest to execute all test added by "add_test" in cmake.

```
user@user:~/<dir to cmake>/cmake/unit_tests$ ctest
Test project /<dir to cmake>/cmake/unit_tests
    Start 1: test_exe
Could not find executable test_exe
Looked in the following places:
test_exe
test_exe
Release/test_exe
Release/test_exe
Debug/test_exe
Debug/test_exe
MinSizeRel/test_exe
MinSizeRel/test_exe
RelWithDebInfo/test_exe
RelWithDebInfo/test_exe
Deployment/test_exe
Deployment/test_exe
Development/test_exe
Development/test_exe
Unable to find executable: test_exe
1/1 Test #1: test_exe ......***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - test_exe (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
```

If I put the "test_exe" in one of the shown paths it works fine. But I don't want them to be there.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to tell ctest it should look in `UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR` in order to find the executable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_test.html) for `add_test()` specifies `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option for *long form* of the command. The value of this option is used as a directory in which test operates:

```
add_test(NAME test_exe COMMAND test_exe WORKING_DIRECTORY ${UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR})
```

If you just want the test to find the executable, it is sufficient to use

```
add_test(NAME test_exe COMMAND test_exe)
```

This is a *long form* of `add_test()` command. In this form, CMake checks whether `COMMAND` is a *target* name, and, if it is so, replaces it with an absolute path to the executable corresponded to that target. Such way the test can be run from any directory.

Note, that automatic replacement of the target doesn't work for a *short form* of `add_test()` which you use.

Comment: This looks like a proper solution! I use `add_test(NAME test_exe COMMAND test_exe WORKING_DIRECTORY ${UNIT_TEST_BIN_OUTPUT_DIR})` now and it works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Note that even though the full path is inserted, the working directory will not be changed in your second snippet. This is important if the test executable uses relative paths.

Comment: @typ1232: Thanks for the comment. I have rephrased the post. Now it should be  clear that the second example do not set working directory.

Comment: I had the same issue and just needed to explicitly specify the parameters NAME and COMMAND.

Answer (score 20):

Using CMake 3.20 and greater, you can tell CTest which directory contains your tests by using a [CLI option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#options):

```
ctest --test-dir /path/to/your/tests
```

This is a less-invasive solution for existing tests, for which you don't want to modify the CMake files.

Comment: Too bad I'm still at 3.16 :x

Comment: I'm looking for that option for a so long time! Thanks. I have had my fill of using "cd build && ctest  & cd .. " and when ctest goes wrong your are not a the right place!

Answer (score 4):

In our projects we always specify the path when we call add_test(), e.g.:

```
add_test( ${filename}  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${filename} )
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way, but it definitly solved it for me! Thank's a lot! Work's fine.